# Faraday's law. Why does the induced current flow this way?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electromagnetic-induction

We have this stationary loop in a time-varying **B**-field. The current ***I*** (in red) is induced by the changing field **B(t)**. This current in turn induces a **B** field that opposes the changing field due to right-hand-rule. But, ***I*** dont understand is why the first field **B(t)** does not obey the right-hand-rule since it induces a current in the opposite direction of what I would expect if I put my fingers in the **B** fields direction and my thumb would point in the opposite of the current that is in the picture. Why does the induced current go that way due to **B(t)**?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If B is increasing, then the indicated induced B and the direction of induced current are correct.  The polarity indicated in red is not. The near side of the resistor will be positive. A voltage drop occurs across the resistor.

Comment: Oh so everything is correct in this image escept for the voltage across the resistor which should be -Vemf according to the picture?

Comment: I'm not sure what is represented by the arrow labeled C.

Comment: You should expand on why the induced B field and current point the way they do so as to help the poster understand.